# What kind of thing is cookies in a rails program?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I've been working my way through http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/ and I'm confused about how `cookies` works.

I'm totally clear on what cookies ARE in the browser, etc. I'm not sure how they are implemented.

In the examples, there's a `sessions_helper` that deals with logging in, etc. That's where cookies are used. It doesn't appear to be inside any specific object (unless all functions defined in the sessions_helper are assumed to be added to the Sessions class?). Cookies is never actually declared. It's never explicitly requested, or anything. So, who owns it? what is it's scope? where is it initialized? what is it's type?

Comment: Check these links for answers to all your questions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: Can people who have downvoted the question let me know how I can improve the question? It's topical for stack overflow. Is it poorly asked? or do people just think it's a dumb question?

Answer (score 0):

On the premise of "to get an answer on the internet, make a claim and see who corrects you" here's what I've got so far:

From the links provided by luisenrike, it appears that the cookies object is declared in ActionController, which is the superclass of ApplicationController, which is the superclass of all actual controllers. So, it is declared and initialized when the (in this case) SessionsController is initialized.

The first question is the one I'm less sure of. It appears that all of the functions in sessions_helper are automatically assumed to be treated as methods in SessionsController.

So, the reason that I can use a cookies object in sessions_helper.rb is that the methods in sessions_helper are in the scope of a SessionsController object, which, through inheritance, is an ActionController, which defines cookies.

EDIT TO ADD:
no, it appears that SessionsHelper is included in the ApplicationController manually. So, in this case, EVERY application controller has access to these functions... 
although it does appear that in GENERAL FooHelper is loaded by the FooController and the Foo Views...